# mock modules works only outside describe statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to mock a function as follow, it works for one test because I can only mock the function outside of `describe`, but when I try to mock that module inside `it` it doesn't work and code as follows:

```
import * as someModule from './someModule'
jest.mock('./someModule')

describe('functions', () => {
    it('do first test', () => {
  //  jest.mock('./someModule')
        expect(jest.isMockFunction(someModule.oneFunction)).toBeTruthy()
    })
})
```

`jest.mock('./someModule')` inside `it` doesn’t work

So, how can I do mocking for only one test?

Comment: jest.isolateModules.

Answer (score 0):

You should `require` the module after calling `jest.mock()`. See [official test case](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4418e7693e13d56deea7f1e6e10ea3cb0158cce5/packages/jest-worker/src/__tests__/index.test.js#L15)

E.g.

`someModule.ts`:

```js
export function oneFunction() {}
```

`someModule.test.ts`:

```js
describe('functions', () => {
  it('do first test', () => {
    jest.mock('./someModule');
    const someModule = require('./someModule');
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(someModule.oneFunction)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66284054/someModule.test.js
  functions
    ✓ do first test (8 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.537 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/66284054